# how to build an app in electron using electron-builder and raspbian?

Tags: raspberry-pi, electron, raspbian, electron-builder

I am trying to export the application using a raspberry that uses raspbian, but I only find errors when I build.

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "author <email@gmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-dragdata": "^1.1.3",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.2.0",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "is-electron": "^2.2.0",
    "mdi-material-ui": "^6.10.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.3",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.75",
    "wait-on": "^4.0.1"
   },
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "public/electron-starter.js",
   "scripts": {
       "react-start": "react-scripts start",
       "react-build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject",
       "electron": "electron .",
       "build": "npm run react-build && npm run electron-build",
       "start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run react-start\" \"wait-on 
           http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
      "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
      "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
      "dist": "electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron-starter.js"
   },
  "license": "MIT",
  "eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
   },
   "browserslist": {
       "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
       ],
   "development": [
       "last 1 chrome version",
       "last 1 firefox version",
       "last 1 safari version"
    ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.1.7",
    "electron-builder": "^22.5.1"
     },
    "build": {
    "extends": null,
    "appId": "com.emulacion.app",
    "productName": "Sistema interactivo",
     "files": [
        "build/**/*",
        "node_modules/**/*",
        "src/assets/**/*",
     ],
    "directories": {
    "buildResources": "assets",
    "output": "build"
     },
    "asar": false,
    "linux": {
        "target": [
           {
              "target": "deb",
              "arch": ["armv7l"]
           }        
         ]
     },
     "win": {
     "target": "portable",
     "icon": "build/icon.ico"
      }
   }
}
```

First I issue the command npm run react-build, so far there is no problem, but when I issue the command npm run dist, it shows the error:

```
cannot execute  cause=exit status 1
            errorOut=/home/pi/.cache/electron-builder/fpm/fpm-1.9.3-2.3.1-linux-
 x86/lib/ruby/bin/ruby: line 6: /home/pi/.cache/electron-builder/fpm/fpm-1.9.3-2.3.1-linux- 
 x86/lib/ruby/bin.real/ruby: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
 /home/pi/.cache/electron-builder/fpm/fpm-1.9.3-2.3.1-linux-x86/lib/ruby/bin/ruby: line 6: 
/home/pi/.cache/electron-builder/fpm/fpm-1.9.3-2.3.1-linux-x86/lib/ruby/bin.real/ruby: Success
```

anyone know how to export the application using electron builder with a configuration for raspbian or do you know why I get that error.

Comment: You can look into the error here and see if this makes sense: https://askubuntu.com/a/648558/1079634

Comment: I don't understand how to apply that, in electron builder so that it builds a 32-bit application